# Installing Solidworks 2015 on Ubuntu 15.04 with wine

Tags: 15.04, wine

I am trying to install SolidWorks 2015 on Ubuntu 15.04 with wine 1.6, and it seems to run the installer, but when the installer opens, what looks like a windows warning box pops up with no content. If I close this window, the installer terminates. I have tried changing the version of windows in wine, to no avail. Nothing is selectable in the window; I have had this issue before with battle.net, but I was still able to click on where the link should have been. I changed wine to run as windows vista to get battle.net to work.

Any thoughts on SolidWorks?

Comment: I tried yesterday as I need it for a course, and the main problem seems to be it is 64bit only, so it doesn't work well with Winetricks' workarounds as those are for 32bit only- I will either have a proper go at solving it this weekend OR will stick a massive bounty on this question (I may need reminding about that). I also needed to workarounds to install it on Windows proper, so it may need quite alot of tweaks to work properly. Which version (academic, industry, whatever) are you using?

Comment: I am using the student version that is provided by my school's license. It is for a year of use while I am attending college. I will try to see if I can find an older version, to find out if it gives me the same issue.

Comment: 2014 32bit might work (see [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29723)) - it may require quite a few workarounds

Comment: N.B. wine 1.7 might work better, for installation see [here](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu), though you may have problems with your battle.net installation then unless you back up the wineprefix

Comment: I'm getting somewhere with 1.7. I can now at least get to the screen that loads the setup manager. Haven't gotten past it yet, but I think I will be able to manipulate some of the settings to get around that. I would rather have SolidWorks installed and functioning than battle.net. I can always set up an additional prefix for that at some point. Thank you for your help! I will post what configuration ultimately works.

Comment: I'm working on it myself and it is fairly easy though I am doing a few workarounds to make life easier. I'll post mine as well - I'm writing it whilst waiting for the stupid download thingy

Comment: the download goes nowhere unless you stimulate the window. hit "close", then when it prompts you if you want to close the window, select "no", and you can get to the screen asking for the serial number. getting past that screen is what I am currently working on. It freezes, and I have to log out and back in to make adjustments to the prefix.

Comment: I get manual download thats going OK so far (I had to do it for Windows 7 - ???) - I had to install Firefox in wine though to stop it complaining.

Comment: Ok it downloaded and said it was installing for me - but it froze or crash each time, so I will file a garbage appDB entry and probably a bug report. If you desperately want it, you may want to get windows for it - you may be able through wherever you are being educated for free, and you can run it in a dual boot setup or a virtual machine.